# How to execute some code after specific thread done its job?

Tags: ios, multithreading, cocoa

I have code like this

```
- (IBAction)onClick:(id)sender {

    NSThread *thread = [[NSThread alloc]initWithTarget:parser selector:@selector(adapter:) object:ph];

    [thread start];
}
```

How can I do something (show log or smth) after thread executed selector i passed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, there is no easy answer to this question without the use of GCD (which is an iOS 4.x feature that you may not be able to support), so use `NSNotificationCenter` and latch into the notification when the method is done.

```
- (IBAction)onClick:(id)sender {

    NSThread *thread = [[NSThread alloc]initWithTarget:parser selector:@selector(adapter:) object:ph];

    [thread start];
}

-(void)adapter:(NSObject*)arg {
    //... process and such
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]postNotification:[NSNotification notificationWithName:@"Thread_Done" object:nil]];

}
```

Comment: i can see how u pass Notification but I can't figure out how to execute some -(void)onPostExecute method after thread done doing -(void) adapter.

Comment: That's easy, replace the notification with this.: `[self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(onPostExecute)];`